# Build micronaut native image with hikari datasource

Tags: hikaricp, micronaut, graalvm-native-image, micronaut-data

Faced with a problem running micronaut application that was packed in native-image.

I created simple demo application with `micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa` and based on documentation I need to add some db connection pool. I chose hikari and added such dependency `micronaut-jdbc-hikari`.

I use maven as build tool and add plugin to build native-image `native-image-maven-plugin`

`native-image.properties`

```
Args = -H:IncludeResources=logback.xml|application.yml|bootstrap.yml \
       -H:Name=demo \
       -H:Class=com.example.Application \
       -H:+TraceClassInitialization \
       --initialize-at-run-time=org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog,org.hibernate.secure.internal.StandardJaccServiceImpl,org.postgresql.sspi.SSPIClient,org.hibernate.dialect.OracleTypesHelper \
       --initialize-at-build-time=org.postgresql.Driver,org.postgresql.util.SharedTimer,org.hibernate.engine.spi.EffectiveEntityGraph,org.hibernate.engine.spi.LoadQueryInfluencers
```

When I run application with the jvm then everything works. But when I try to run same application that was packed as native-image then I get such error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag$IConcurrentBagEntry[] is instantiated reflectively but was never registered. Register the class by using org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.RuntimeReflection
    at com.oracle.svm.core.graal.snippets.SubstrateAllocationSnippets.arrayHubErrorStub(SubstrateAllocationSnippets.java:280)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:305)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:195)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:172)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.borrow(ConcurrentBag.java:129)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:179)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:471)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:352)
    ... 99 common frames omitted
```

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

Based on @Airy answer I have added reflection config in native-image.properties. In my case it is looks like so

```
[
  {
    "name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
    "allPublicClasses" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolEntry",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
    "allPublicClasses" : true
  }
]
```

And another solution is to change scope of hikari dependency to compile and add missed fields/classes into hints annotation like so

```
@TypeHint(value = {
        PostgreSQL95Dialect.class,
        SessionFactoryImpl.class,
        org.postgresql.PGProperty.class,
        UUIDGenerator.class,
        com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.class,   // In my case I have just added this line

}, accessType = {TypeHint.AccessType.ALL_PUBLIC})
```

whole example you can find [here](https://github.com/aleksei-bulgak/micronaut-nativeimage-example/tree/hikari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare reflection configuration in your `native-image.properties` with `-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=/path/to/reflectconfig`

[Here is the documentation for doing so](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/REFLECTION.md#manual-configuration)